# Как добавить столбец в столбец в sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram, aiogram

Делаю бота в телеграмме на `aigram`(новичёк) и к нему подключил бд `sqlite3`.

Добавил `id` юзера.
У каждого юзера будет фильм,который он может выбрать и изменить там запись
То есть в бд это должно выглядить так:

```
id: #уже добавил,обьяснять не надо
    films: #Название фильма который он добавил
            1)
            2)
            3... #и тд
```

То есть я понимаю как добавить `id` и по нему показывать какие то данные, но как вот в столбец `films` добавить по сути еще один столбец в котором и будут эти самые фильмы, а дальше в каждом фильме 1 2 3 и тд записей этих фильмов(то есть на какой минуте к примеру остановился, или минута интересного момента).

Бот будет выдавать так: Напишите название фильма(написал).Напишите запись для этого фильма(написал) Вот все ваши фильмы,выберите записи какого фильма хотите посмотреть?выбрал - фильм,и бот показывает все записи этого фильма то есть 1) 2) 3) и тд.

Comment: Ну а ты просто в строке храни с каким-то сепаратором между разными фильмами. Или, к примеру, закинь фильмы в массив потом переведи его в джисон как строку и сохраняй в столбец.

Comment: Извините,очень сложно,можно попонятнее?)

Comment: Ну так ловишь хендлером название фильма, обращаешься через юзер айди телеграмма к твоей бд, проверяешь нет ли уже записей, если есть получаешь, иначе делаешь тупо список с одной строкой (которую ввел юзер), импортирует модуль json и в просто json.dumps(list_films). Хоба и у тебя строка в формате джисон которую ты отправляешь в бд, где поле films у тебя строкового типа.

Comment: а как то без махинаций с json не получится сделать?просто я наверное вопрос не понятно составил..Это ведь должно быть можно сделать только в бд разве,нет?Попробую по другому сформулировать как в боте выглядит: Бот спрашивает название фильма,юзер пишет его,фильм добавляется в бд к этому пользователю.Юзер нажимает показать список фильмов(как показать список фильмов из бд я понимаю)выбирает фильм из списка и нажимает добавить запись,что то пишет,и эта запись добавляется именно к этому фильму в бд(записей может быть сколько угодно как и фильмов,1 2 3 4 5 и тд)

Comment: Это типичное соотношение много-ко-много (один юзер может править несколько фильмов, один фильм могут править несколько юзеров), которое требует наличия связующей таблицы.

Comment: А как это сделать то?(Много юзеров если что не могут править один фильм,у каждого юзера свой список фильмов и заметок)